# JS get array in string using toString (without changing the actual array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, string, controller

I'm trying to convert a js array to string. This string should be a value of a hidden input as so:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="myIndicationsString" />
```

In the controller:

```
 $scope.myIndicationsString = $scope.productIndications.toString();
```

The problem is, it changes the array to a string value so when a change is needed to occur in $scope.productIndications it fails to do so. 
Is there a method like toString() without changing the actual element? only returning a string result?
Thanks before

Comment: are you saying that it converts array to string once, and after the value of productIndications changes, it wont assign the new stirng value?

Comment: @DarshanNReddy I'm saying that it changes the array to string and then other array actions won't apply on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to generate a string representation of your array, like this:

```
 $scope.myIndicationsString = JSON.stringify($scope.productIndications);
```

This function will not modify the original array, so you'll be able to continue using that as before. If you need to turn that string that `stringify` returns back into an array, you can use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to do so.

Comment: Thanks! Works great (although a $watch is needed on $scope.productIndications for every change so that $scope.myIndicationsString will be updated as well)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are exactly asking but [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) might be what you are looking for.

Let say your array is `array = [John, Steve, Rob, Mary, Tom]`, then what you can do is:

`array.join(',') \\John,Steve,Rob,Mary,Tom 
array.join(' ') \\John Steve Rob Mary Tom 
array.join('And') \\JohnAndSteveAndRobAndMaryAndTom`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly confused what you are asking, however, assuming you are using angularjs, you can make an identical copy of a scope variable as to maintain the state of the original variable.

```
var test = [1, 2, 3],
    test2;

angular.copy(test, test2);
```

test2 should now be an identical copy that you can manipulate, without affecting test.